# Cohomology of Klein bottle in $Z_n$ coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to compute cohomology group of Klein bottle $K$ in $Z_n$ coefficients.

I've got that $H^0(K)=Z$ and by using [UCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem), I've got that $H^1(K,Z_n)=Hom(Z\oplus Z_2,Z_n)=Z_n\oplus Z_{gcd(2,n)}$ and $H^2(K,Z_n)=Ext(Z\oplus Z_2,Z_n)=Z_{gcd(2,n)}$.

Is everything ok with my result?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is correct. And $H^0 (K; \mathbb{Z}_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_n$ (again, by the UCT).

Comment: @Don Alejo Thanks.